# How the range at which the radiation is emitted get affected with changing temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation

If the emitting body is blackbody, then the range at which radiation is emitted won't change, because a blackbody is a blackbody whether the temperature is 4000K or 120000K, meaning that, by definition, it emits at ALL wavelengths. However, I am wondering, how things would work for a grey body let's say. My guess is that the answer stays the same, because, for example, let's say the range at which the radiation is emitted increases with increasing temperature, then theoretically speaking, a grey body can be turned into a blackbody at high enough temperature, which I don't think happens in nature.

Comment: *it emits at ALL the wavelengths* Yes, but much more at some wavelengths, and negligibly at others, and that behavior is very much temperature-dependent.

Comment: I am asking about the rage at which radiation is emitted when increasing temperature for bodies less perfect than the blackbody, how would the RANGE change? I am saying that even when the bodies aren't blackbody, the range won't change, what do think?

Comment: I think you’re wrong. The range where, say, 99% of the power is emitted is *highly* temperature-dependent, both for blackbodies and greybodies.

Comment: So you're saying that with increasing temperature a grey body would emit at wavelengths it didn't emit at previously?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I’m saying.

Comment: But that means that you're also saying that a grey body can turn into a blackbody at high enough temperature!

Comment: I think that’s a *non sequitur*, but we can’t have an extended discussion in comments.

Comment: Why that's non sequitur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A grey body emits a blackbody spectrum with a lower emissivity ($<1$), where the emissivity is independent of wavelength/frequency. NB. This is the [definition of a grey body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body#cite_note-emissivity-3). (See also [here](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095907858)).

So if a blackbody radiates at all wavelengths, then by definition, so does a grey body (but less).

Comment: *emissivity is independent of wavelength/frequency* Due to Hawking radiation, black holes are greybodies with frequency-*dependent* emissivity. Is the emissivity of a normal hot object really independent of frequency?

Comment: @Ghoster no I'm sure it isn't. But the emissivity of a **grey body** is a constant, by definition. Black holes are black bodies.

Comment: *Black holes are black bodies.* No, [they aren’t](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_greybody_factors). This has been known since at least 1976, when Don Page [calculated](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.13.198) their frequency-dependent greybody factors.

Comment: Fair enough. Black holes are not grey bodies either. @Ghoster https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803095907858

Comment: People doing black hole greybody calculations don’t use that definition of greybody. I’ll stop arguing.

Answer (score 1):

> If the emitting body is blackbody, then the range at which radiation
> is emitted won't change, because a blackbody is a blackbody
> whether the temperature is 4000K or 120000K,

This is not true. Looking at the blackbody spectra below, you see
that the wavelength range of the radiation changes with temperature.

- It radiates in all wavelengths. But the radiation is mainly
  concentrated to a range of wavelengths. And there is only
  little radiation outside of this range.
- This range of wavelength shifts more and more to shorter
  wavelengths with increasing temperature.
  This is known as [Wien's displacement law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law).
  For example: At temperature $T=2000$ K the radiation is mainly
  in the infrared, while at $T=5000$ K it is mainly in the visible
  region.
- The total radiation (summed over all wavelengths) increases
  with temperature.
  This is known as the [Stefan-Boltzmann law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law).
  For example: At $T=5000$ K the total radiation is around $40$
  times more than at $T=2000$ K.

[image: Blackbody spectra at various temperatures]
<sub>(image from [Blackbody Radiation - Physics LibreTexts](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/University_Physics_%28OpenStax%29/University_Physics_III_-_Optics_and_Modern_Physics_%28OpenStax%29/06%3A_Photons_and_Matter_Waves/6.02%3A_Blackbody_Radiation))</sub>

> However, I am wondering, how things would work for a grey body let's say.

By definition, a [grey body](https://e-learning.gunt.de/WL420/html/en_Basic%20knowledge%20on%20heat%20transfer/0000000042.htm) at a certain temperature
has the same emission spectrum  as a black body
at that temperature, only scaled down by a factor $\varepsilon < 1$.

[image: gray body spectrum]
<sub>(image from [Black/grey/white body - E-Learning at GUNT](https://e-learning.gunt.de/WL420/html/en_Basic%20knowledge%20on%20heat%20transfer/0000000042.htm))</sub>

Comment: I didn't say the radiation doesn't  change, I said the *RANGE* of wavelengths doesn't change and I think you just confirmed that.

Comment: @Jack ok, I have corrected my phrasing.

Answer (score 0):

> If the emitting body is blackbody, then the range at which radiation is emitted won't change, because a blackbody is a blackbody whether the temperature is 4000K or 120000K, meaning that, by definition, it emits at ALL wavelengths.

A blackbody would perfectly *absorb* all wavelengths.   It will emit radiation based on its temperature.  The specific spectrum of radiation follows a particular curve the depends only on temperature.

Any real object would have a different emission spectrum.  You can raise the temperature of a grey body, but it will not emit as much as as a black body when both are at the same temperature.

> A blackbody at any temperature emits at all wavelengths

In practice, the power of wavelengths below a particular cutoff are so low that there is no difference between their emission and zero.   (You would have to wait many universe lifetimes before a 300K black body emitted a thermal xray photon).

> would a grey body emits at more wavelengths given a higher temperature?

If you go by the definition that a black body emits at all wavelengths at all temperatures, then a grey body does as well.  It just emits less than the black body for any given temperature and wavelength band.

Comment: A blackbody at any temperature emits at all wavelengths. At a lower temperature, it still emits at all wavelengths, but with less amplitude. My question is, would a grey body emits at **more wavelengths** given a higher temperature?